# RDP to home PC with Windows Hello PIN

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a Windows machine at home that is using my Microsoft account, and I login using PIN. How do I RDP to that machine?

In the RDP client, there is no option to sign in using PIN, only password. When I tried to use my MS account + password, it says "The logon attempt failed".

I know I can disable the option "Require Windows Hello sign-in for Microsoft accounts", and just remove the Hello PIN altogether, but I would like to sign in using PIN when I'm using the machine, but at the same time allow me to RDP using either PIN, or username+password.

How do I:

1. Set the RDP client to sign in using PIN?
2. Or... how do I enable the Windows machine to enable login with both PIN and username+password?

This is all at home settings, no AD, no domain-joined, both the host (Windows 10 Professional) and client (Mac) is at home in the same network.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e48f3809-617f-4a5b-8f4e-8f231d47addc/using-rdp-to-login-in-a-windows-hello-pin-secured-pc?forum=win10itpronetworking

Comment: I believe it’s part of the PIN concept that it can only be used on the device itself. If it could used over the network, that would be a tremendous security issue.

Comment: Interestingly, Chrome Remote Desktop lets you use the PIN, over the network.  Of course, CRD has a couple of separate authentication steps as well (your Google account, and a host-specific password).

Answer (score 3):

Might be late to the party, but I found this post because I was having the same issue.  Same environment and same machines

What I did was go to `Settings -> Remote Desktop`

Under the User Accounts header, select `Select users that can remotely access this PC`

In the popup, click `Add` and then click `Advanced` and finally click `Find Now`

Scroll through the list until you find your name and email address that are in the folder for what your PC is named (Farid-PC, Desktop-W7283 or something similar)

Select the user, and then click `OK` on all the open windows.

You should now be able to RDP to the machine using your Live email address and password

Comment: worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

I know you mentioned that you are using a Mac for the client, but I'm going to assume that Microsoft's RDP client for Mac has a feature similar to the client on Windows that addresses this. I don't have access to a Mac to test.

If you're using the Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection program `mstsc.exe`, go to the Advanced tab then click the checkbox for "Use a web account to sign in to the remote computer". When you connect a window will open to allow you to enter your credentials.

[image: Screenshot of the Advanced tab in the Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection program for Windows]

Comment: Saved my life, saved my day, God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 professional and higher have Remote Desktop server abilities. Windows 10 Home does not.

According to [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10-security/using-remote-desktop-connection-to-pc-with-windows-hello-pin/m-p/133579) forum post, the RDP doesn't play well with Windows Hello. You are probably better off using a traditional password. [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/950448/cannot-connect-to-remote-desktop-with-windows-hello-pin) is some more information that could help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason to be that my Microsoft account was switched to passwordless, so in doing so, RDP asks for a password, even if you have it set to pin/smartcard on the actual machine, so without re-adding the password, it will always say invalid password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in with a regular account password, after the login fails you still should be able to see the windows login screen (if you entered the correct password). I am connecting to azure so it says: "The sign-in method you are trying to use isn't allowed...", Click OK button, and try looking for "Sign-in options" button. Then it will give you option to login with pin. Type in Windows Hello Pin and you should be able to enter.